# Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed on WCF service with windows froms application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have the code like this:

```
public DataTable GetScriptDetails()
{
    DataTable dtScriptDetails = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=sample;Initial Catalog=ScriptManagement;User ID=sa;Password=abcde");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ScriptName,UploadDate from ScriptDetails", con);

    using (SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            dtScriptDetails.Load(dataReader);
        }
        dataReader.Close();
    }
    con.Close();
    return dtScriptDetails;
}
```

but I got this error:

**Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.**

I have searched a lot but unable to solve this.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked your connection string? Is it ok? I mean can you connect to your database using the connection string you have provided to the `SqlConnection`?

Comment: Yes. It's working fine for another method in which I am inserting some values to DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTable.Load method loads all the data from the reader. You do not need to loop through any of the rows in your reader. So, in your code, you can remove the loop and have something like this:

```
using (SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
            dtScriptDetails.Load(dataReader);
     }
```

Comment: Thanks. That solved my problem but now while getting the data I am getting the error: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:62476/DeploymentMangerService.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Comment: My code is like :

DeploymentMangerServiceClient objDeploymentMangerClient=new DeploymentMangerServiceClient();
            DataTable dtScriptdetails=objDeploymentMangerClient.GetScriptDetails();

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this fixes the issue but use if+`HasRows` instead of of a loop + `Read`:

```
using (SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (dataReader.HasRows)
    {
        dtScriptDetails.Load(dataReader);
    } // no need to close it if you use using
}
```

However, I would use a `SqlDataAdapter` to fill the table:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dtScriptDetails);
```